# How Can I access to my virtual machine with ip?

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I have Oracle Virtual Box installed on Ubuntu 10.10. I want to gain access to my script that runs on local. My virtual operating system connects via network and takes an ip address, but how would someone access my script that runs on local? Which ip address can be used?

Comment: is is setup doing NAT or is it getting an IP from your internal network.  IF is it doing nat, you will need to port forward from your computer to it, or change to have it obtain/use an address on your network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

type this from your host os
and you have to open the port 80 from guest OS (Ubuntu)
http://you_virtual_machine_ip

Comment: Ok, but how can Someone who in my local area access?

Comment: once you open the port 80 of your guest os .. and if it's a bridged network then any one in n/w can access it

Answer (score 1):

If you use bridged network and your VM is on Ubuntu 10.10. One easy way is to use ssh. By default ssh is installed and configured in Ubuntu 10.10. You can connect to it by :

```
ssh you_virtual_machine_ip
```

ssh is a powerful tool and your can run scripts when connected to the host.
If you are in Windows System, [Putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) is a great tool of ssh client.